# Tooltip delay on hover with RXJS

Tags: reactjs, rxjs, settimeout, delay, react-portal

I'm trying to add tooltip delay (300ms*emphasized text*) using rxjs (without setTimeout()). My goal is to have this logic inside of TooltipPopover component which will be later be reused and delay will be passed (if needed) as a prop.

I'm not sure how can I add "delay" logic inside of TooltipPopover component using rxjs?

Portal.js

```
const Portal = ({ children }) => {
  const mount = document.getElementById("portal-root");
  const el = document.createElement("div");

  useEffect(() => {
    mount.appendChild(el);
    return () => mount.removeChild(el);
  }, [el, mount]);

  return createPortal(children, el);
};

export default Portal;
```

TooltipPopover.js

```
import React from "react";

const TooltipPopover = ({ delay??? }) => {

  return (
    <div className="ant-popover-title">Title</div>
    <div className="ant-popover-inner-content">{children}</div>
  );
};
```

App.js

```
const App = () => {

  return (
        <Portal>
          <TooltipPopover>
            <div>
              Content...
            </div>
          </TooltipPopover>
        </Portal>
  );
};
```

Then, I'm rendering TooltipPopover in different places:

```
ReactDOM.render(<TooltipPopover delay={1000}>
                        <SomeChildComponent/>
                </TooltipPopover>, rootEl)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here would be my approach:

```js
mouseenter$.pipe(
  // by default, the tooltip is not shown
  startWith(CLOSE_TOOLTIP),

  switchMap(
    () => concat(timer(300), NEVER).pipe(
      mapTo(SHOW_TOOLTIP),
      takeUntil(mouseleave$),
      endWith(CLOSE_TOOLTIP),
    ),
  ),

  distinctUntilChanged(),
)
```

I'm not very familiar with best practices in React with RxJS, but this would be my reasoning. So, the flow would be this:

- on `mouseenter$`, start the timer. `concat(timer(300), NEVER)` is used because although after 300ms the tooltip should be shown, we only want to hide it when `mouseleave$` emits.
- after 300ms, the tooltip is shown and will be closed `mouseleave$`
- if `mouseleave$` emits before 300ms pass, the `CLOSE_TOOLTIP` will emit, but you could avoid(I think) unnecessary re-renders with the help of `distinctUntilChanged`